# Adding imageMSO to a custom ribbon group

Tags: excel, xml, ribbonx

When you resize excel - ribbon would auto-scale to fit. And if needed groups are replaced with a single button. [imgur.com/ahxyADt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRtHi.png)

But as you can see it uses a placeholder with custom groups.

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691834(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#auto-scaling-of-custom-controls):

> You can specify the icon that appears when the group is compressed to a single button by assigning an image to the group itself.

However I cannot assign imageMSO to the group even though it's [listed in attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)#group).

I get an error *The 'imageMSO' attribute is not declared.* in Office RibbonX Editor. And if I apply XML anyways - nothing happens.

Is there a way to apply imageMSO?

PS: I tried 'image' attribute with embedded picture and that works.  But not imageMSO.

---

Turned out that i had a typo in camelCase. Instead of `imageMso` i had `imageMSO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what value is assigned to the `imageMso` attribute. The fact is that `imageMso` accepts only built-in controls IDs. You can find the list of controls IDs in the [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745).

If you want to use a custom icon you need to specify the `image` attribute or implement the `getImage` callback. The callback has the following signature:

```
C#: IPictureDisp GetImage(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)

C++: HRESULT GetImage([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] IPictureDisp ** ppdispImage)

Visual Basic: Function GetImage(control as IRibbonControl) as IPictureDisp
```

Comment: I'm familiar with imageMSO as I use them for my buttons. However I'm having trouble with using it with groups.

As I mentioned in my question, I managed to use *image* attribute. However I'd like to use Office Library instead of painting images in paint.

Comment: What value exactly did you try to specify for the `imageMso` attribute?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Turned out that i had a typo in camelCase. Instead of imageMso i had imageM**SO**

Comment: If the problem is solved I'd suggest marking the post as answer.